# VIM - do not leave visual mode after doing something with it

Tags: vim

In vim, when I am in visual mode and do something with it, like e.g. indenting some lines, after the operation is applied, I am thrown back into normal mode. How can I change this behavior so that I stay in visual mode until I press Esc? I would like to be able to e.g. indent the lines once more immediately after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if there's a way to change the behavior for all of the visual mode. I find the indentation behavior odd too and I have a visual mode mapping in my `.vimrc` for fixing this

```
vnoremap > >gv
vnoremap < <gv
```

#### Explanation

`vnoremap` -> non-recursively remap in visual mode

`gv` -> selects the previously selected visual selection

So, creating a visual mode mapping for the keystoke(s) you're using and suffixing it with `gv` would make sure you stay in the visual mode. Maybe not the best way, but it works, interested to find if there are better ways.

Comment: thank you, this is a good workaround for the moment :) I will wait for more answers though before accepting this as a solution

Comment: @maddingl, the solution suggested here is a classic that you can find in thousands of `vimrc`s. You should accept it.